# Concating multiindex dataframes

Tags: pandas, concatenation, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe, with the outer-layer index consisting of stocks names, and the innerlayer index consisting of dates.

```
                     Open        High        Low         Close
AAPL    2010-01-04  213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998  
        2010-01-08  210.299994  212.000006  209.060005  211.980005

OPK     2010-01-04  213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998  
        2010-01-08  210.299994  212.000006  209.060005  211.980005
```

I'm have a new dataframe with some dates not included in the original dataframe, and I want to append them.

```
                       Open          High        Low         Close

AAPL    2010-01-09  219.429998  219.499996  212.380001  214.009998  
        2010-01-10  219.299994  219.000006  209.060005  211.980005

OPK     2010-01-09  219.429998  219.499996  212.380001  214.009998  
        2010-01-10  219.299994  219.000006  209.060005  211.980005
```

So the output I'm looking for is

```
                      Open       High        Low         Close
AAPL    2010-01-04  213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998  
        2010-01-08  210.299994  212.000006  209.060005  211.980005
        2010-01-09  219.429998  219.499996  212.380001  214.009998  
        2010-01-10  219.299994  219.000006  209.060005  211.980005

        2010-01-04  213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998  
        2010-01-08  210.299994  212.000006  209.060005  211.980005
OPK     2010-01-09  219.429998  219.499996  212.380001  214.009998  
        2010-01-10  219.299994  219.000006  209.060005  211.980005
```

I tried variations of these

```
    pd.concat([stocks_df, df])
    pd.concat([stocks_df, df], levels = [stocks_df.index] )
```

but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: What I know suggests the first variation should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([stocks_df, df]).sort_index()
print (df)
                       Open        High         Low       Close
AAPL 2010-01-04  213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998
     2010-01-08  210.299994  212.000006  209.060005  211.980005
     2010-01-09  219.429998  219.499996  212.380001  214.009998
     2010-01-10  219.299994  219.000006  209.060005  211.980005
OPK  2010-01-04  213.429998  214.499996  212.380001  214.009998
     2010-01-08  210.299994  212.000006  209.060005  211.980005
     2010-01-09  219.429998  219.499996  212.380001  214.009998
     2010-01-10  219.299994  219.000006  209.060005  211.980005
```

Comment: This seems to work. However, strangely, the order of the columns is coming back changed, as in mixed up in the new df. I'm getting `Index(['15_Avg_Vol', '20_Avg_Vol', '30_Avg_Vol', '5days', '7days',
       '7days_10daysAvg', '9_Avg_Vol', 'Adj Close', 'Close', 'Daily_Change',
       'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume', 'changed'`
      dtype='object') `  

The smaller `df` that I'm concatanating, has fewer columns (the ones 
 in above OP only) than the larger one. However, they both start off with `['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']`, so not sure why the order is being changed.